# Hide a div based on specific page URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
if (/menu/.test(window.location.href)) {
    document.getElementById('searchfield').display = 'none';
 }
}
</script>
```

I would like to do this with JavaScript or JQuery -- thus far my attempts are not working. I have a div that is to be present on all pages but 1 page; in which I would like to hide it with JavaScript if that page.

*Note: This is a Wordpress website; the above was inserted in the header.php head of the document. Same location of repetitive div.*

Comment: Are you calling `myFunction` on each page?

Comment: `document.getElementById('searchfield').style.display` You missed `.style`

Comment: And you need to call this function when document is ready.
`$(myFunction);`

Comment: The condition is completely confusing to me. What should be test(window.location.href) to hide the div? I mean what is the page alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myFunction` is never called. You'll need to explicitly call it when the page is ready `$(myFunction);`, or if you want, call it in the footer (or close to it) directly with `myFunction();`.

An alternative, since this is a WordPress site, is to add PHP code to not show that div (or even send it to client!) based on a filter.

Another alternative is using CSS to block out that specific div on the page that's loaded.

Answer (score 2):

This is easier with CSS.

HTML (make sure all of your pages have some unique identifier, generally on the `body` tag):

```
<body id="page-1">

    <div id="menu">

    [ ... ]
```

CSS

```
#page-1 #menu{
    display:none;
}
```

**Edit**

I see you're working in WordPress. WP automatically adds unique classes to the body tag. Generally you can use something like this for your CSS:

```
.page.page-id-34{
    /*
        34 should be swapped with the page id.
        You can customize the classes,
        so just Inspect Element and see what it is for your page
     */
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: CSS should always be the first choice!